# How to access browser's Session Storage using Blazor SSR (no interactivity). .Net8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Using Blazor SSR with no interactivity.
I need to read Session Storage during the init of each page.
I've tried Nuget 'Blazored.SessionStorage', but that requires interactivity.
I've also tried HttpContext.Session.GetString, but could not get that to work.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
 //--- Test HttpContext - Fail 
private async Task Test1()
 {
 HttpContext.Session.GetString("testKey");
 }


//--- Test NuGet Blazored.SessionStorage - Fail 
 private async Task Test2()
 {
     await sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("name", "John Smith");
     var name = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("name");
 }
```

Comment: You're trying to read the browser's session state. That requires some kind of interactivity, whether it's Blazor's interactive mode or your own custom JavaScript code that reads the state and posts it back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you using SSR, accessing Session will be the same as in the Asp.net Core MVC. You could write excution code in a `@{...}` brace. Try following in a SSR page:
program.cs

```
...
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
...
app.UseSession();
```

Home.razor

```
@page "/"
@{
    httpContext.Session.SetString("name", "John Smith");
    Name = httpContext.Session.GetString("name");
}

@Name

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]HttpContext? httpContext{ get; set; }

    private string Name = "";
}
```

Test result
[image]
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-razor-components-blazor

Comment: I tried this out and it works. But it writes a cookie with an expiration of 'session' which is not the same as writing to Session Storage. The big difference being that with a cookie, one cookie is created regardless of the number of tabs open in the browser and the session ends when the browser is closed.  With Session Storage, each tab creates it's own session record and the session end when the tab is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [that document](https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage). You can try to use OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method. Here is a code example :

```
string name = string.Empty;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await session.SetItemAsync("name", "John");
        name = await session.GetItemAsync<string>("name");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

If you wanna see another example you can check [here](https://github.com/BetulTugce/WeatherForecast/blob/master/WeatherForecast/WeatherForecast.UI/Pages/Index.razor).

Comment: This code is for Blazor with interactivity. The sample in the link uses .net 7 Blazor. .net7  Blazor did not have the SSR option. Blazor SSR (no interactivity) was introduced in .net8. Also, if using Blazor SSR there is no prerending.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).